# Queries without Aggregate or SubQuery

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm wondering if it is possible to find all instructors that teach 'Math' and does not teach 'English', **without** using aggregate **or** subqueries.

My normal approach is to use subqueries/aggregates by finding all those that teach English and use: where instructor not in (select instructor from course where course = 'English') or to group by instructor, course having count(*) > 1.

// Test Input and Output below

```
CREATE TABLE testTable (instructor TEXT, course TEXT);

INSERT INTO testTable values ('John Doe', 'Math');

INSERT INTO testTable values ('John Doe', 'English');

INSERT INTO testTable values ('John Doe', 'Physics');

INSERT INTO testTable values ('Jane Doe', 'Math');

INSERT INTO testTable values ('John Smith', 'Physics');

INSERT INTO testTable values ('John Smith', 'Math');

INSERT INTO testTable values ('Janice Smith', 'English');
```

Solution should be:

```
Jane Doe

John Smith
```

Comment: What's wrong with using aggregates and subqueries? Is your "normal approach" not working for some reason?

Comment: I've been told to avoid subqueries so I'm trying to learn other approaches to problems like this where the normal approach is using subqueries/aggregates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `join`s

```
select tm.instructor
from t tm left join
     t te
     on tm.instructor = te.instructor and te.subject = 'English'
where tm.subject = 'Math' and te.instructor is null;
```